# Laravel 8 controller api returning "page not found" in axios react

Tags: reactjs, laravel, axios

Laravel controller API returning "page not found" while consuming it from Axios in Next.js But everything is working fine in PostMan with the following code

Controller function:

```
public function viewsnippets(Request $request)
{
    $slug = $request->slug;
    $postdata = Constant_model::getDataOneColumn('snippets', "url_slug", $slug);

    if ($postdata->count() < 1) {
        $data['status'] = 404;
        $data['title'] = 'Page Not Found';
        $data['description'] = 'Page Not Found';

        return response()->json($data);
    }
    $snippet_id = $postdata[0]->id;
    $snippet_title = $postdata[0]->snippets_name;
    $data['status'] = 200;
    $data['snippet_title'] = $snippet_title;
    $data['slug'] = $slug;

    return response()->json($data);
}
```

Model File:-

```
public static function getDataOneColumn($table, $col1_name, $col1_value)
{
    $data = DB::table("$table")->where("$col1_name", '=', $col1_value)->get();

    return $data;
}
```

React File

```
const [snippets, SetSnippets] = useState();
const {slug} = router.query;
var data = {
    slug: slug,
}
var config = {
    headers: {
        accept: '*/*',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'API_ACCESS_KEY': 'hns2V0Ddbkkn8r1XLq3Kw7ZoiBTR0nmA',
    }
};
const url = 'api/viewsnippets';
useEffect(async () => {
    await axios.post(url, data, config)
        .then(function (response) {
            console.log(response.data);
            SetSnippets(response.data);
        });
}, []);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to put a `/` in front of your `url` otherwise the request will be relative to the current page URL:

```
const url = '/api/viewsnippets';
```